# Does asp.net use reflection to parse and build objects based on server control tags?

Tags: asp.net

If so, are the results cached after the first access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be confused as to what reflection really is. It's not a tool for parsing and creating objects, but rather analyzing meta data on CLR types. Here's the [official overview of reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Now, once ASP.Net creates instances of objects represented by markup (xml), it uses reflection to fill in property values on the newly created objects and does cache the metadata. It does all of this during the page initialization phase of the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).